# How to solve error while updating sqlite3 data in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

While doing my project, I had to update a data into another data. I tried to delete the existing old data and insert new data, but this procedure changes the order of data, so I don't want that kind of method.

What I am trying to do is to find a data which has values of `old` and replace it to the values in `new`. So this is the code I've made:

```
    import sqlite3

    old = ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4')
    new = ('Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_3', 'Test_4')

    conn = sqlite3.connect('TestDB')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (Menu1 text, Menu2 text, Menu3 text, Menu4 text)")
    conn.commit()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Test VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", old)
    conn.commit()

    c.execute("UPDATE Test SET Menu1 = ? and Menu2 = ? and Menu3 = ? and Menu4 = ? WHERE Menu1 = ? and Menu2 = ? and Menu3 = ? and Menu4 = ?", new + old)
    conn.commit()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Test")
    print(c.fetchall())
```

But I had a problem updating the data set: the result of the code was:

```
[('0', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4')]
```

So why on earth am I having this problem and how can I solve this problem? I've been trying to solve this problem for days and I still couldn't solve the probelm.

Comment: Can you try calling `conn.commit()` after the update?

Comment: Oh I did `conn.commit()` but missed to write it while posting. Thanks though!

Comment: You are using `and` in the `SET` section of `UPDATE`, where you should be using `,`. `UPDATE Test SET Menu1 = ? , Menu2 = ? , Menu3 = ? , Menu4 = ? WHERE Menu1 = ? and Menu2 = ? and Menu3 = ? and Menu4 = ?`

Comment: Seems like I was confused about the syntax. It works, thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, normally you don't need to call `conn.commit() explicitly, you should use a `with` statement to automatically commit/rollback when the scope is exited normally/via exception

Comment: Ow, no primary key? Normally the `WHERE` clause matches based on (only) that, otherwise you get bad performance

Comment: Well I've never used primary keys handling sqlite and I've never seen bad performance

Comment: I don't use `conn.commit()` explicitly in actual code - I used it several times just showing the process

Answer (score 0):

The statement `UPDATE Test SET Menu1 = ? and Menu2 = ? and Menu3 = ? and Menu4 = ? WHERE Menu1 = ? and Menu2 = ? and Menu3 = ? and Menu4 = ?` is wrong. It is parsed as

1. `UPDATE`, "Test", `SET`
2. "Menu1", `=`, `?`
3. `AND`, "Menu2", `=`, `?`
4. `AND` ...
5. ....

The `AND` in 3. turns the whole statement beginning with 2. into an expression. `Menu1 = ? AND Menu2 = ? ...` is coerced into a boolean which is `True` if the first parameter is "true-ish" and "Menu2" is equal to the second parameter, and "Menu3" is equal to the third parameter and so on. The result of this expression is `False`, which is coerced into the `0` that you see.

The statement you probably want is something to the tune of

`UPDATE Test SET Menu1 = ?, Menu2 = ?, .... WHERE Menu1 = ? ...`.